# How to get the row# nearest to current time in SQLite for Android rawQuery

Tags: android, sqlite

Experts,
I would like to get the value from column MyColumn, where column Judge is true, and column DateTime is closest to current time. How to approach this? Thanks.

I develop code like below seems work. However, when the table **contains rows only Judge='false'**, (expect to get 0 rows since one of my where condition is Judge='true') I got:

cursor.moveToFirst()==true

cursor.getCount()==1

And therefore a 0.0 assigned to myColumn instead of 999999.

```
 String dateTime="CURRENT_DATE_TIME";
 double myColumn;

 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select MyColumn, " +
                "min(strftime('%s', '" + dateTime + "') - strftime('%s', DateTime)) " +
                "from trade1 " +
                "where Judge = 'true' " +
                "and date(DateTime) <= date('" + dateTime + "')", null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        myColumn = cursor.getDouble(0);  

        if (cursor.getCount()==0) myColumn = 999999;


        cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use an aggregation function like MIN() without GROUP BY, you get a result over all rows, even if there are none.

Just add `GROUP BY Judge`.

(And you must no try to read from the cursor before you have checked for a valid row.)

Comment: but when got 0 row from the query, I would like to set myColumn=999999, how to know if it is 0 row from the cursor?

Comment: sorry I dont get it, how to know if it is 0 row from the cursor by use if/else? I tried to judge getcount,movetofirst, etc. all are true when 0 row

Comment: Got it,  treat aggregation function result as additional row(s). Thanks a lot!